# I try generate query that retrieve all fields from my relational model and successfully caught the query

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

```
que = RuleCondition.objects.select_related('rule_id', 'operator_id', 'value_id', 'variable_id', 'rule_specification_id')

print(que.query.__str__())
```

The generated query is:

> SELECT `de1_rulecondition`.`id`, `de1_rulecondition`.`rule_id_id`,`de1_rulecondition`.`rule_condi_id`, `de1_rulecondition`.`rule_condi_seqno`, `de1_rulecondition`.`variable_id_id`, `de1_rulecondition`.`operator_id_id`, `de1_rulecondition`.`value_id_id`, `de1_rulecondition`.`rule_specification_id_id`, `de1_rulecondition`.`function`, `de1_rulecondition`.`logical_operator`, `de1_rulecondition`.`leftPara`, `de1_rulecondition`.`rightPara`, `de1_rulecondition`.`created_by`, `de1_rulecondition`.`created_date`, `de1_rulecondition`.`updated_by`, `de1_rulecondition`.`updated_date`, `de1_rule`.`rule_id`, `de1_rule`.`rule_threshold_id_id`, `de1_rule`.`rule_name`, `de1_rule`.`rule_type`, `de1_rule`.`description`, `de1_rule`.`rule_category`, `de1_rule`.`created_by`, `de1_rule`.`created_date`, `de1_rule`.`updated_by`, `de1_rule`.`updated_date`, `de1_variables`.`variable_id`, `de1_variables`.`variable_description`, `de1_variables`.`data_type`, `de1_variables`.`standared_format`, `de1_variables`.`created_by`, `de1_variables`.`created_date`, `de1_variables`.`updated_by`, `de1_variables`.`updated_date`, `de1_operators`.`operator_id`, `de1_operators`.`operator`, `de1_operators`.`no_of_val`, `de1_operators`.`created_by`, `de1_operators`.`created_date`, `de1_operators`.`updated_by`, `de1_operators`.`updated_date`, `de1_rulevalue`.`value_id`, `de1_rulevalue`.`rule_id`, `de1_rulevalue`.`rule_condi_id`, `de1_rulevalue`.`rule_condi_seqno`, `de1_rulevalue`.`default_value`, `de1_rulevalue`.`created_by`, `de1_rulevalue`.`created_date`, `de1_rulevalue`.`updated_by`, `de1_rulevalue`.`updated_date`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`id`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`rule_id`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`rule_condi_id`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`rule_condi_seqno`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`value_id`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`specified_value`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`created_by`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`created_date`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`updated_by`, `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`updated_date` FROM `de1_rulecondition` INNER JOIN `de1_rule` ON (`de1_rulecondition`.`rule_id_id` = `de1_rule`.`rule_id`) INNER JOIN `de1_variables` ON (`de1_rulecondition`.`variable_id_id` = `de1_variables`.`variable_id`) INNER JOIN `de1_operators` ON (`de1_rulecondition`.`operator_id_id` = `de1_operators`.`operator_id`) INNER JOIN `de1_rulevalue` ON (`de1_rulecondition`.`value_id_id` = `de1_rulevalue`.`value_id`) INNER JOIN `de1_rulespecifiedvalues` ON (`de1_rulecondition`.`rule_specification_id_id` = `de1_rulespecifiedvalues`.`id`)

How can be remove these redundant columns such as created_by etc...?